# reset On Resolve the course to loop in React

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm trying to reset the Values on change of the Dependency value to the SelectInput. But it course to loop and break the page. Here find the code I have done so far.

How can omit this on my code.

```
import {
    SelectInput,
    required
} from 'react-admin';
import data from '../data';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DependentInput } from 'aor-dependent-input';

const initialState = {
    way_of_join: data.way_of_join
};

class WayOfJoinSelectInput extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = initialState;
    }

    reset(){
        this.setState({initialState});
    }

    switchSector = (props) => {
        if (props !== undefined && Object.keys(props).length > 0) {
            var value = props.General_Service.service_sector;
            this.reset();
            switch (value) {
                case 'sleas':
                    this.state.way_of_join.splice(4, 3)
                    break;
                case 'sltes':
                    this.state.way_of_join.splice(2, 1)
                    break;
            }
        }

    };

    render() {
        return (
            <DependentInput resolve={this.switchSector}>
                <SelectInput
                    source="General_Service.way_join"
                    label="Way of Join"
                    validate={required()}
                    // onChange={this.reset()}
                    choices={this.state.way_of_join}
                />
            </DependentInput>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(WayOfJoinSelectInput);
```

Here find what getting on error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import {
SelectInput,
required
   } from 'react-admin';
  import data from '../data';
  import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import { DependentInput } from 'aor-dependent-input';

const initialState = {
   way_of_join: data.way_of_join
  };

 class WayOfJoinSelectInput extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = initialState;
    this.reset=this.reset.bind(this);
}

reset(){
    this.setState({initialState});
}

switchSector = (props) => {
    if (props !== undefined && Object.keys(props).length > 0) {
        var value = props.General_Service.service_sector;
        this.reset();
        switch (value) {
            case 'sleas':
                this.state.way_of_join.splice(4, 3)
                break;
            case 'sltes':
                this.state.way_of_join.splice(2, 1)
                break;
        }
    }

};

render() {
    return (
        <DependentInput resolve={this.switchSector}>
            <SelectInput
                source="General_Service.way_join"
                label="Way of Join"
                validate={required()}
                 onChange={this.reset}
                choices={this.state.way_of_join}
            />
        </DependentInput>
    )
}
}

export default withStyles(styles)(WayOfJoinSelectInput);
```

**You need to bind the functions in constructor or use arrow functions.**

Comment: what you mean by it? you are posting the same code what I posted in the question.

Comment: you might misunderstood the question, please re-read it. your current answer is irrelevant

Comment: I did not post the same question as answer. In your code, you were calling the onchange handler in render method as  onChange={this.reset()}. My thought was not to call it in render. you need to bind the handler in constructor.

Comment: yes , but then also your changes wont solve this issue.

Comment: @JigarShah Do you know how solve this? pleas give me suggestion if have any.

Comment: @MohamedNizar you need to change logic for this line `<DependentInput resolve={this.switchSector}>` in render, which calls `this.reset();` and state changes will lead to re-rendering again `this.switchSector` this is called and so on ...  You have to prevent call to  `this.reset()` by adding some condition and try to move code in `componentDidMount()` if possible